# Linux: Recover files from .vdi file

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, data-recovery, ext4

Somehow my `.vdi` (Linux guest OS) file got corrupted. Now I have some files in it (Inside the `vdi` file) and I want to recover those files. How can I do that?

Comment: probably not possible if your file (and not the filesystem on it) corrupted, you can try http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/145028/linux-recover-files-from-vdi-file

Comment: What filesystem is on it? ext4?

Comment: Do you know the reason for the corruption? If you haven't identified it, it could corrupt other files. Run a memory test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're on a Linux host as well (you didn't mention that). You can always try the Network Block Device (NBD) option:-

```
sudo modprobe nbd max_part=16
sudo qemu-nbd -c /dev/nbd0 <path to your vdi file>
ls -lh /dev/nbd0*
<lists all the partitions on the vdi>
```

Choose which of the partitions you want to mount (eg 1st partition), then:

```
sudo mount /dev/nbd0p1 /mnt
```

That may work, depending on how corrupt your `vdi` file is.  You can use normal filesystem tools on this mount and or dev node.

When done, unmount it and:-

```
sudo qemu-nbd -d /dev/nbd0
```

**Note:** You may have to install `qemu-nbd` depending on your distro. Package `qemu-utils` on Ubuntu, `qeu-img` on Fedora.

If you're on Windows you may have some success by following [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=4748).

An alternative Windows way would be to quickly install another Linux VM and then add your `vdi` file as additional disk to that VM.  You can then use the NBD procedure above on it.

Comment: This solution still works 3/17, Only thing I would add is ``sudo apt install qemu``

Answer (score 0):

If you are abe to boot the guest OS then I think you need to install a package which will work as a recovery tool for your file system.Remember the packege will change from Filesystem to file system.Few which i know are available at
for ext4 http://extundelete.sourceforge.net/
you can also check this out
https://askubuntu.com/questions/41601/is-there-any-recovery-software-available-for-ext4

and if you are not able to boot into the guest os then you first need to recover the vdi file then by booting into guest os you can recover the files.

Remember No bosy guarantees you 100% recovery of files.